# Moshiach already in heaven?

Tags: messiah, gan-eden, masechet-derech-eretz

[Masechet Derekh Eretz Zuta](https://www.sefaria.org/Tractate_Derekh_Eretz_Zuta.1.18?ven=The_Minor_Tractates_of_the_Talmud,_trans._A._Cohen,_London:_Soncino_Press,_1965&lang=he&with=all&lang2=he) says:

> ט׳ **נכנסו** בחייהם בג״ע. ואלו הן חנוך בן ירד ואליהו **ומשיח** ואליעזר עבד אברהם וחירם מלך צור ועבד מלך הכושי ויעבץ בנו של רבי יהודה הנשיא ובתיה בת פרעה וסרח בת אשר ויש אומרים אף ר׳ יהושע בן לוי

If Moshiach is yet to come, why is נכנסו used? Does the use of נכנסו not suggest that Moshiach has entered גן עדן already?

Answer (score 1):

The [Yaabetz](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Tractate_Derekh_Eretz_Zuta.1.18?ven=The_Minor_Tractates_of_the_Talmud,_trans._A._Cohen,_London:_Soncino_Press,_1965&with=Haggahot%20Ya%27avetz&lang=he) there points out that there were others who entered Gan Eden while alive but later were sent out, Adam and his sons and an Ammora רב"א. We could say similarly that Moshiach is now in Gan Eden and will soon be sent out to reign in this world.

Answer (score 0):

"If Moshiach is yet to come" why should we assume he isnt? That the person of moshiach is here does not mean that such a person is revealed or even more that the redemption is here. Just like it says Eliyahu Hanavi will come back and announce the redemption, so too this moshiach would return to do the redemptive process afterwards. However, one is not forced to deal with this. One can simply reinterpret this as the Aggados eliyahu does on similar midrashim about moshiach as a person who was taken but who whose soul will go into a moshiach who is down here. One could also take the approach Ramban offers in his debates where he says I need not accept this medrish at all. I recently saw someone in the past generation(finable on otzar) try to argue that this text was altered by the christians to make it sound like jesus, but really the original wasnt like this. He brings a proof from how other sources bring the source. Feel free to take your pick.

Answer (score -1):

I always enjoy reading the JewishTimes of [Mesora.org](http://www.mesora.org/index.html). Sometimes, I contribute and write a question myself. You can see an example of that [here](http://www.mesora.org/jewishtimes565.pdf). I bring this up because it is nearing Shabbat and I do not have time to write a full answer adequately, but I feel the latest JewishTimes answered this well. The question asks how Elijah (Eliyahu) is still alive in heaven, and we can apply the same to the Messiah. The answer is the following:[1]

> Rambam holds that angels exists only in man’s visions, meaning, not on
> earth. And “wandering spirits” are not a reality. I don’t know how
> Rambam would answer this. But everyone dies. Such sayings intend to
> convey some praise of Eliyahu. About Jacob, Chazal said he didn’t die.
> But Torah says he was embalmed. Evidently Chazal’s meaning is not
> literal. The rabbis say, “never dying” means there was minimal
> dierence between one's life and death. Highly perfected people
> experience minimal change between life and death, it is as slight as a
> kiss, which is the term Chazal use about Moses’ and Aaron’s deaths:
> they both died “with a kiss.” Miriam did as well, bit it isn’t
> appropriate to talk about G-d kissing a woman (Rashi). It is notable
> that the 3 most perfected people were siblings. Talmud also says their
> father Amram was 1 of 4 people who never sinned.[2]

[1] To see the orgional answer, see [here](http://www.mesora.org/jewishtimes.pdf).

[2] If you enjoy this answer by the JewishTimes, feel free to subscribe to their mailing list. Rabbi Moshe Ben-Chaim writes many interesting, thought-provoking essays because they make us think.

Comment: The problem with proving from Yaakov to Eliyahu is the Torah describes Yaakov's death, but Eliyahu is described as ascending to heaven miraculously. As such, there's no need to assume it's not literal that he didn't die. Also, this doesn't adequately answer the question about Moshiach entering gan Eden.

Comment: @robev I just got a book in the mail today about the Biblical Elijah. I waited to open it and now look forward to reading it. Among much else, the book takes the approach that the fiery chariot is a metaphor for his death. The author is an orthodox rabbi.